# Jquery autocomplete dentro de modal

Tags: jquery, html5

Olá estou com um problema ao utilizar jquery em um modal, fora do modal o script funciona corretamente porém se eu colocar o input dentro do modal ele não funciona.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
        <title>Teste de JQuery</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                $(function(){
                    var esportes = ["Natação","Basquete","Futebol"];
                    $("#esporte").autocomplete({
                        source: esportes
                    });
                });
                </script>
</head>

<body>

        <input type="text" id="esporte" placeholder="digite um esporte"><!--Onde ocorre o autocompletar-->

        <div class="container">
                <h2>Modal Example</h2>
                <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header">

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">


</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: edite a pergunta e inclua o código completo lá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está em dois pontos.
1º a classe 'modal' define um z-index de 1050;
2º o plugin do 'jquery-ui' na classe 'ui-front'  um z-index de 100;

Ou seja se você alterar o z-index da classe 'ui-front' para 1051 deve funcionar.

[image: Printscreen]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
 <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
 <title>Teste de JQuery</title>
 <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <style>
  .ui-front{
   z-index: 1051;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">

      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
      </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="text" id="esporte" placeholder="digite um esporte">
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     </div>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function () {
   var esportes = ["Natação", "Basquete", "Futebol"];
   $("#esporte").autocomplete({
    source: esportes
   });
  });
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Resolveu amigo muito obrigado!!!!